# Problems with delegate and callback funcitons - fsharp, Exchange Managed API

Tags: f#, ews-managed-api

The following code works with a lambda function:

```
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668.aspx#Create
#r "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

open Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
open System

let exchangeService emailAddress password = 
    let service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
    service.Credentials <- new WebCredentials(emailAddress,password) 
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress, (fun (redirectionUrl:string) -> redirectionUrl.ToLower().StartsWith("https://") ) )
    service
```

But I have problems when I bind the lambda used in AutodiscoverUrl to a name:

```
let x (redirectionUrl:string) = redirectionUrl.ToLower().StartsWith("https://")
service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress, x)
```

Visual Studio complains about "x".

"This expression was expected to have type Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback but here has type string -> bool"

Note that this is the same signature as the lambda function above.  Inspected using f# interactive...

```
fun (redirectionUrl:string) -> redirectionUrl.ToLower().StartsWith("https://")
val it : redirectionUrl:string -> bool = <fun:clo@1>
```

and

```
let x (redirectionUrl:string) = redirectionUrl.ToLower().StartsWith("https://")
val x : redirectionUrl:string -> bool
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling a method that takes a delegate as an argument, F# lets you call it with a lambda function and automatically converts it to a delegate (which is why your first version works).

I think that not all versions of F# automatically convert named functions to delegates, so when you want to use a named function as an argument, you can do that by creating a delegate explicitly. This means that if you want to pass the function `x` as an argument you can write:

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback (x))
```

In this case, it is probably shorter to wrap it in a short inline lambda function:

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress, fun arg -> x arg)
```

**EDIT:** In the latest version of F#, the conversion from named functions to delegates should work too - but I think it depends on what kind of delegate this is, what other overloads are there and which F# version are you using. The above should always work though.

Comment: Thanks Tomas.  "Conversion to the delegate" makes sense - hence the error message.